# WPF,C#: Multiple declarations of popup creating problems

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, prism, region

I have a Prism WPF app that uses popups.  The same functionality is needed in multiple places, so I've got my popup referenced like so.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CreateCatalogsRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
            <interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>

                <!-- Problem line below -->
                <view:SomePopUpView />

            </interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
    </interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This exact same snippet of code appears in two controls at the moment. When I comment out the code, or replace "SomePopupView" with a standard component (Combobox) my app works.  When I have it referencing the same component (SomePopupView) twice, my app chokes complaining about regions.

I don't want to have to rewrite or extend or do any architecture voodoo, but how do I get the same popup functionality in different parts of the app?

Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT** The solution as provided by AnjumSKhan works.  My solution is as follows

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <view:SomePopupView x:Key="SomePopupView" />
    ....
<Application.Resources>
```

View with duplicated popup

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CreateRequestInteraction, Mode=OneWay}">
        <interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
            <interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource SomePopupView}"></ContentControl>
            </interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
    </interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Declare your `Popup` as a `Resource`.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it so others can clearly see it's a solved question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution.

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <view:SomePopupView x:Key="SomePopupView" />
    ....
<Application.Resources>
```

View with duplicated popup

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CreateRequestInteraction, Mode=OneWay}">
        <interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
            <interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource SomePopupView}"></ContentControl>
            </interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
    </interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```